# Error on an Icomparer Implementation. Please help !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, icomparer

I created an array sorter to sort arrays like in Win Explorer in a DNN module. As in the answer to a preview question:

[Sorting an array of folder names like Windows Explorer (Numerically and Alphabetically) - VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099581)

A user is getting the following error (below) whenever they run the module, I'm not a particularly seasoned ASP.NET developer. Is this error caused becuase I used [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx) in my IComparer and is being used on a platform that does not support StrCmpLogicalW. Or is it caused becuase of a permissions issue.

Any help is much appriciated,

Thanks a huge lot.

Here's the sorter that causes the error.

```
Public Class nvSorter
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Declare Unicode Function StrCmpLogicalW Lib "shlwapi.dll" ( _
        ByVal s1 As String, _
        ByVal s2 As String) As Int32

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y)
    End Function

End Class
```

And this is the Exception stack trace :

> InnerException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.
>
> Message: 
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---|> 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---|> System.Security.SecurityException: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission at Nukeville.Modules.SkinLab.View.nvSorter.Compare(String x, String y) at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.SwapIfGreaterWithItems(T[] keys, IComparer`1 comparer, Int32 a, Int32 b) at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.QuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer) at System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, IComparer`1 comparer) at Nukeville.Modules.SkinLab.View.GetNVFolder(String ParentName, String[] cf) at Nukeville.Modules.SkinLab.View.GetJavaFolderArrays(String RootPath) at Nukeville.Modules.SkinLab.View.Page_PreRender(Object s, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security issue. You can't [p/invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) [StrCmpLogicalW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947%28VS.85%29.aspx) from a [partial trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650058.aspx) ASP.NET environment.

Comment: Are there any solutions to make this comparer work in a partial trust environment as well? Or switch to another simple 'alphabetic sorting' comparer if this could not run ?

Comment: You would have to implement `StrCmpLogicalW()` in managed code, which won't be easy. Fortunately, [there's hope](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting).

Comment: Thank you for all your help  :) .. I started another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165662/ any help would be appriciated.