# Sorting arrays numerically and alphabetically(like Windows Explorer) without using StrCmpLogicalW or shlwapi.dll - ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting

I created a sorter that StrCmpLogicalW / shlwapi.dll. unfortunately it causes errors on partial trust environments. I am in a really bad need of a solution that does not use 'shlwapi.dll' or StrCmpLogicalW and works in the same fashion.

Here's the sorter that causes the error.

```
Public Class nvSorter
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Declare Unicode Function StrCmpLogicalW Lib "shlwapi.dll" ( _
        ByVal s1 As String, _
        ByVal s2 As String) As Int32

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer
        Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Filenames() As String = New String() {"0", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
        Array.Sort(Filenames, New CustomComparer)
        MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", Filenames))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CustomComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Private Position As Integer
    Private Order As Integer = 1

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal Ascending As Boolean = True)
        If Not Ascending Then
            Order = -1
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function EmptyText(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return String.Empty.Equals(s)
    End Function

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Dim res1 As New List(Of String)(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(x, "(\d+)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Dim res2 As New List(Of String)(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(y, "(\d+)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        res1.RemoveAll(AddressOf EmptyText)
        res2.RemoveAll(AddressOf EmptyText)
        Position = 0

        For Each xstr As String In res1
            If res2.Count > Position Then
                If Not IsNumeric(xstr) AndAlso Not IsNumeric(res2(Position)) Then
                    Dim intresult As Integer = String.Compare(xstr, res2(Position), True)
                    If intresult <> 0 Then
                        Return intresult * Order
                    Else
                        Position += 1
                    End If
                ElseIf IsNumeric(xstr) And Not IsNumeric(res2(Position)) Then
                    Return -1 * Order
                ElseIf Not IsNumeric(xstr) And IsNumeric(res2(Position)) Then
                    Return 1 * Order
                ElseIf IsNumeric(xstr) And IsNumeric(res2(Position)) Then
                    Dim res As Integer = Decimal.Compare(Decimal.Parse(xstr), Decimal.Parse(res2(Position)))
                    If res = 0 Then
                        Position += 1
                    Else
                        Return res * Order
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Return -1 * Order
            End If
        Next

        Return 1 * Order
    End Function
End Class
```

The result of the above sorting example of `"0", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"` is:

[image]

Comment: Following lines of code give an error "ToList" in not a member of "System.Array":
Dim res1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(x, "(\d+)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToList

Dim res2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(y, "(\d+)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToList

Comment: Tim .. thank you for all your help. There are no errors ... but its not sorting at all , I think.

Comment: You have a WinFowm `Form1` with a Button `Button1` on it?
It is sorting, but I'm not sure if its exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Array without sorting of any kind : ["0","1","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","2","20","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

with new sorting applied = ["3","0","20","4","2","8","5","7","19","6","18","11","17","10","12","1","16","13","15","9","14"];

Comment: with new sorting applied :
["3","0","20","4","2","8","5","7","19","6","18","11","17","10","12","1","16","13","15","9","14"];

Comment: I think its not doing what was intended. :)

Comment: The same array with the old StrCmpLogicalW sorting applied:
["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"];

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, you will see that this is exactly the result of "my" CustomComparer ;-)
How do you have implemented the Comparer?

Comment: :) silly mistake .. sorry ... Workd beautifully now :) Thank you super much ! you saved me !