# sorting when name includes letters and numeric digits

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I have following array

```
[0] = GB_22_T0001.jpg
[1] = GB_22_T0002.jpg
[2] = GB_22_T0003.jpg
[3] = GB_22_T0006.jpg
[4] = GB_22_T0007.jpg
[5] = GB_22_T0008.jpg
[6] = GB_22_T0009.jpg
[7] = GB_22_T00010.jpg
[8] = GB_22_T00011.jpg
[9] = GB_22_T00012.jpg
[10] = GB_22_T00013.jpg
```

I have put this items in a listbox and noticed that 'GB_22_T00010' comes straight after 'GB_22_T0001' instead of 'GB_22_T0002'

Seems to be a common issue with c# but cannot find a common answer to the problem.

I tried sorting the array with Array.sort(data) and also tried LinQ's OrderBy method but none of them helps.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: What are the actual items you are storing? If each one is an object already, just add a variable to it that stores the last numeric part, and then sort it on that using LINQ.

Comment: This is expected because you are sorting as strings. If you want a mixed comparison, then the #2 "Related" question offered by SO has the answer: [Sorting an array of folder names like Windows Explorer (Numerically and Alphabetically)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099581/sorting-an-array-of-folder-names-like-windows-explorer-numerically-and-alphabet) (Surprised you said you couldn't find a common answer since it's right there.)

Comment: It looks like whoever made the file names made a silly mistake. The numbers following T all start with 000 which makes me think they were aware of this, but they don't use that padding when the number grows to more digits! I would expect to see ... 0008 0009 0010 0011 0012 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GB_22_T0001` is a string not a number. So it's sorted lexicographically instead of numerically. So you need to [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) a part of the string to an `int`.

```
var ordered = array.Select(Str => new { Str, Parts=Str.Split('_') })
                   .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Parts.Last().Substring(1))) 
                   .Select(x => x.Str);
```

`Split('_')` splits the string into substrings on a delimiter `_`. The last substring contains your numeric value. Then i use `String.Substring` to take only the numeric part(remove the starting `T`) for `int.Parse`. This integer is used for `Enumerable.OrderBy`. The last step is to select just the string instead of the anonymous type.

**Edit**: Here is the version that supports `Paths`:

```
var ordered = array.Select(str => { 
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
    string[] parts =  fileName.Split('_');
    int number = int.Parse(parts.Last().Substring(1));
    return new{ str, fileName, parts, number };
 })
.OrderBy(x => x.number)
.Select(x => x.str);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add .jpg at the end. Will this code work with .jpg at the end of the string?

Answer (score 5):

This is my code to sort a string having both alpha and numeric characters.

First, this extension method :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AlphanumericSort(this IEnumerable<string> me)
{
    return me.OrderBy(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(50, '0')));
}
```

Then, simply use it anywhere in your code like this :

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() { "The 1st", "The 12th", "The 2nd" };
test = test.AlphanumericSort();
```

How does it works ? By replaceing with zeros :

```
  Original  | Regex Replace |      The      |   Returned
    List    | Apply PadLeft |    Sorting    |     List
            |               |               |
 "The 1st"  |  "The 001st"  |  "The 001st"  |  "The 1st"
 "The 12th" |  "The 012th"  |  "The 002nd"  |  "The 2nd"
 "The 2nd"  |  "The 002nd"  |  "The 012th"  |  "The 12th"
```

Works with multiples numbers :

```
 Alphabetical Sorting | Alphanumeric Sorting
                      |
 "Page 21, Line 42"   | "Page 3, Line 7"
 "Page 21, Line 5"    | "Page 3, Line 32"
 "Page 3, Line 32"    | "Page 21, Line 5"
 "Page 3, Line 7"     | "Page 21, Line 42"
```

Hope that's will help.

Answer (score 3):

Windows has a built-in comparison function that you can use to compare strings like this (mix of strings and numbers):  `StrCmpLogicalW`

You can use it as the guts of a IComparer to do your sorting.

This blog entry has many details about this: http://gregbeech.com/blog/natural-sort-order-of-strings-and-files

It works really well.

**Edit:**  The implementation I used based on the above blog:

```
public sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
  public static readonly NaturalStringComparer Default = new NaturalStringComparer();

  public int Compare(string x, string y)
  {
    return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
  }
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
  [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
  public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}
```

Then to be used using LINQ:

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i, new NaturalStringComparer());
```