# Complete folder picture viewer in c#

Tags: c#, image, viewer

I am a complete newbie when it comes to programing. I followed the tutorial here to create a picture box. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-u s/library/dd492135.aspx
I work in c#. Now i am going through and making some changes.  Is there anyway to make a code so that there can be a next and back button?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks,
Rehan

Comment: yes there are.. you may want to show some example and ask another question

Comment: What you'll want to do is switch the OpenFileDialog for a [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx), build a collection of images in the selected folder then the Next/Back buttons would step through the collection and update the display.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to have two buttons *(Next, Back)*
I make a little project and I will be happy if it helped you.

If you want this, continue reading:

[image]

First we have to declare `imageCount` and a `List<string>`: `Imagefiles`
so we have this

```
List<string> Imagefiles = new List<string>();
int imageCount = 0;
```

`imageCount` helps to change images using buttons

`Imagefiles` contains all Image paths of our photos

Now to change photos we have to declare a path first which wil contains all photos.
I use `FolderBrowserDialog`

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
    {
        findImagesInDirectory(fbd.SelectedPath);
    }
 }
```

You will see that I use `findImagesInDirectory` and this method doesnt exist. We have to create it.
This method will help us to filter all the files from the path and get only the image files

```
private void findImagesInDirectory(string path)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach(string s in files)
    {
        if (s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png")) //add more format files here
         {
            Imagefiles.Add(s);
         }
     }
     try
     {
         pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Imagefiles.First();
     }
     catch { MessageBox.Show("No files found!"); }

}
```

I use `try` because if no image files, with the above extension, exists code will break.

Now we declare all Image files *(if they exists)*

Next Button

```
    private void nextImageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageCount + 1 == Imagefiles.Count)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Other Images!");
        }
        else
        {
            string nextImage = Imagefiles[imageCount + 1];
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = nextImage;
            imageCount += 1;
        }
    }
```

Previous Button

```
    private void prevImageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(imageCount == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Other Images!");
        }
        else
        {
            string prevImage = Imagefiles[imageCount -1];
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = prevImage;
            imageCount -= 1;
        }

    }
```

I believe my code help. Hope no bugs!

Comment: The order in which files are retrieved is not always the order the user expects, though. I advise sorting the array at some point before using it.

Comment: You have a point but, I cant think a possible code right now. If you have something in your mind, post it!

Comment: The `List` class simply has a `.Sort()` function which, without arguments, takes the default comparator. For `String`, that'd be normal alphabetical. Though it can also be given an `IComparer` object to use more advanced methods. I [know one here that sorts it the way Windows explorer does.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3099659/395685)